# Insert data from custom PHP function into MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, function

I'm having problems inserting a particular line of code into my MySQL database. It inserts three rows just fine, but the "html_href" row isn't going in for whatever reason. Here is my code:

```
    function html_path() {
        $title = strtolower($_POST['title']);       // convert title to lower case
        $filename = str_replace(" ", "-", $title);  // replace spaces with dashes
        $html_href = $filename . ".html";               // add the extension
    }
```

And my MySQL query code:

```
    $query = "INSERT INTO work (title, logline, html_href, synopsis) VALUES";
    $query .= "('".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title'])."',";
    $query .= "'".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['logline'])."',";
    $query .= "'".html_path()."',";
    $query .= "'".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['synopsis'])."')";

    $result = mysql_query($query);
```

The title, logline, and synopsis values go in just fine, but the `html_href()` function inserts a blank row.

Comment: Your `html_path()` function has no return value. I'm guessing you want it to return `$html_href`.

Comment: Also, don't forget the mysql_real_escape_string on $_POST['title'].  There's an SQL injection vulnerability otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your `html_path()` function isn't returning anything.

Try:

```
function html_path() {
    $title = strtolower($_POST['title']);       // convert title to lower case
    $filename = str_replace(" ", "-", $title);  // replace spaces with dashes
    $html_href = $filename . ".html";               // add the extension
    return $html_href;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your html_path() does not return the $html_href variable. Add

```
return $html_href;
```

before you close it, and it should work perfectly.

Comment: You are very welcome - remember to mark the correct answer when you are satisfied :)